# How to keep input and output shape consistent after applying conv2d and convtranspose2d to image data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm using Pytorch to experiment image segmentation task. I found input and output shape are often inconsistent after applying Conv2d() and Convtranspose2d() to my image data of shape [1,1,height,width]). How to fix it the issue for arbitrary height and width?
Best regards

```
import torch

data = torch.rand(1,1,16,26)

a = torch.nn.Conv2d(1,1,kernel_size=3, stride=2)
b = a(data)
print(b.shape)    

c = torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(1,1,kernel_size=3, stride=2)
d = c(b)
print(d.shape)    # torch.Size([1, 1, 15, 25])
```

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. Can’t be on purpose. You should probably submit a bug report to the torch project!

Comment: @CrisLuengo why are you saying this is a bug? It's not because you expect something to work a certain way that it is supposed to do so. This is actually the expected behavior for `nn.ConvTranspose2d`. Have a look a the corresponding documentation page, or to the answer below for a quick overview ;)

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR; Given the same parameters `nn.ConvTranspose2d` is not the invert operation of `nn.Conv2d` in terms of dimension shape conservation.**

From an input with spatial dimension `x_in`, [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) will output a tensor with respective spatial dimension `x_out`:

```
x_out = [(x_in + 2p - d*(k-1) - 1)/s + 1]
```

*Where `[.]` is the whole part function, `p` the padding, `d` the dilation, `k` the kernel size, and `s` the stride.*

**In your case:** `k=3`, `s=2`, while other parameters default to `p=0` and `d=1`. In other words `x_out = [(x_in - 3)/2 + 1]`. So given `x_in=16`, you get `x_out = [7.5] = 7`.

On the other hand, we have for [`nn.ConvTranspose2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html?highlight=convtranspose2d#torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d):

```
x_out = (x_in-1)*s - 2p + d*(k-1) + op + 1
```

*Where `[.]` is the whole part function, `p` the padding, `d` the dilation, `k` the kernel size, `s` the stride, and `op` the output padding.*

**In your case:** `k=3`, `s=2`, while other parameters default to `p=0`, `d=1`, and `op=0`. You get `x_out = (x_in-1)*2 + 3`. So given `x_in=7`, you get `x_out = 15`.

However, if you apply an output padding on your transpose convolution, you will get the desired shape:

```
>>> conv = nn.Conv2d(1,1, kernel_size=3, stride=2)
>>> convT = nn.ConvTranspose2d(1, 1, kernel_size=3, stride=2, output_padding=1)

>>> convT(conv(data)).shape
torch.Size([1, 1, 16, 26])
```